# How to convert milliseconds to date in MVEL for ElasticSearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, mvel

I need to convert a unix_timestamp field to date by MVEL operators.

I have a field which is filled by a mysql imported timestamp. Now I am to get the day date (not datetime) from it and use it in an aggregation.

My Aggregation is like this:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "grouped_item" : {
    "terms" : {
      "script" : "doc['time_stamp'].value",
      "size" : 50
    }
  }
}
```

The result of above aggregate is grouped 'by second', but I need 'by date'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to value script this and use the terms aggregation, use the [date histogram aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) that exists for exactly this purpose.